# How can I make API calls from within an Appium and WDIO test?

Tags: appium, webdriver-io

I am using Appium and Webdriver IO (WDIO).

I need to make API calls to the backend to setup and data and retrieve data during the test.

I can do some of this if I use the before function, but the test fails if I use it in the actual test.

Is it possible to make backend calls during these tests?

FYI, I am using async await and axios.

Comment: Hi, Please try this and see it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791594/how-to-use-3rd-party-method-that-takes-callback-in-webdriverio/51848936#51848936

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a code sample, it is hard to say what is wrong, but definetly there is a way to make it work.

The first thing to question: are you running wdio in sync mode (default)?

If so, you may have an issue trying to make an API call with async/await (e.g. [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) library) in the same test.

Have you tried using `browser.call`? [Check the docs](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/browser/call.html), it basically the way to do what you want with wdio wrapper.

Still failing? Try to increase test suite timeout (e.g. mocha timeout in case of Mocha)