# Send HTTP POST while testing native app with webdriverio

Tags: node.js, appium, webdriver-io

I'm testing a native ios/android app using a webdriverio boilerplate (https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate) project as basis.

But for some scenarios I need to put a user with a precondition info, and for that i want to send a HTTP request to a webserver to set the info for that user.

There is any way to send a post wile using webdriverio an appium on native apps?

I'm trying to send the post after initialize the app but nothing seems to be happening...

Comment: Hi, Could you please share the piece of code that you using to make the http-post request.

Answer (score 1):

You can make HTTP POST request using webdriverio. It doesn't matter what the mode of test(appium, selenium, cucumber, etc.,.)

Please try this answer if this helps:

[How to use 3rd party method that takes callback in webdriverio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51791594/how-to-use-3rd-party-method-that-takes-callback-in-webdriverio/51848936#51848936)